# XHR post requests fail with CORS

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cors

I want to access example.com from another domain test.example.com.
I have already setup the server example.com to respond header with CORS header like this (in nginx.conf):

```
     add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;
     add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
     add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS";
     add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*";
```

If I send a GET request which can suceed, but if I send a POST request which will fail with this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/path. Origin http://test.example.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

How can I do post request with cors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on the browser. Some browsers do not like a wildcard in Access-Control. Try to put all headers of the post request in Access-Control-Allow-Headers (e.g. from Access-Control-Request-Headers).

Please note also that for basic GET requests you usually do not need any specific server extensions - this could be an explanation why GET works (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

If this does not work: Can you give us more details about which browser are you using and what requests it makes.

Comment: Thanks. My server's response code is not 200, which also caused some problems.